# Flipping a Conditionally Unfair Coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a coin that is fair at the initial flip. Whenever we get the head, the coin becomes unfair with $\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{H}) = p > 0$. Whenever we get the tail, the coin becomes fair again. Suppose we flip the coin for $N$ times, what is the expected value of heads that we get throughout the $N$ flips when $N$ is large?

Below is my attempt:

Thanks to the hint by @lulu, we simply start with the unfair coin, and the flips can now be comprehended as a repetition of the following events:

> - The coin remains unfair (i.e., remains head) for a series of flips
> - the coin becomes fair (i.e., remains tail) for yet another series of flips.

To put simply, the process of flipping can be understood as
$$
\underbrace{\rm HH\cdots H}_{h_1\text{ heads}}\overbrace{\rm TT\cdots T}^{t_1\text{ tails}}\cdots\underbrace{\rm HH\cdots H}_{h_i\text{ heads}}\overbrace{\rm TT\cdots T}^{t_i\text{ tails}}\cdots,
$$
where $h_i, t_i \geqslant 1$.

Let $X_i$ denote the number of flips in the $i$-th such cycle by $X_i = H_i + T_i$, where $H_i$ and $T_i$ denote the number of heads and tails. Note that the $X_i$'s are i.i.d., and the expected values are:
$$
\mathbb{E}H_i = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}(H_i = n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot p^n = \frac{p}{(1 - p)^2}.
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}T_i = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}(T_i = n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot 2^{-n} = 2.
$$
Therefore $\mathbb{E}X_i = 2 + p/(1-p)^2$. Now, by the Renewal Theorem, letting $C_N$ denote the number of occurrences of such cycles before the $N$-th flip (i.e., $C_N = \sup\{n: \sum_1^n X_i \leqslant N\}$) we have
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{C_N}{N} \to \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}X_i} = \frac{(1-p)^2}{2(1-p)^2 + p}.
$$
Thus, when $N$ is large,
$$
C_N\approx \frac{N(1-p)^2}{2(1-p)^2 + p},
$$
and the expected number of heads to have through these flips is
$$
\frac{Np}{2(1-p)^2 + p}.
$$

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural first step might be to solve this for small $N$ and look for patterns.  As another suggestion, symmetry might lead one to consider the same problem with the same rules only assume you start with the unfair coin.

Comment: @lulu I have added my attempt to the question description. could you please take a look?

Comment: The final formula doesn't sound right in the extreme case $p=1$, where it gives $N$ itself for the expected number of heads in $N$ tosses.

Comment: @BarryCipra  That formula is, I think, intended to be an estimate for large $N$.  It is not exact for small $N$.

Comment: @lulu, I think you're right. I had skipped to the bottom line, and didn't look closely at how it was derived.

Comment: @BarryCipra My bad. I should have said that $N$ is large.

Comment: Interesting approach.  My idea had been to let $E_n$ be the desired result, $F_n$ the result given that you started with the biased coin (otherwise same rules) and then to get a double recursion.  It is not obvious to me that this double recursion implies your large $N$ estimate....

Comment: The double recursion is:  $E_n=\frac 12\times E_{n-1}+\frac 12\times (F_{n-1}+1)$ and $F_n=q\times E_{n-1}+p\times(F_{n-1}+1)$.  One can easily use this to get a recursion of depth $2$ for the $E_n$ alone, and looking at the characteristic polynomial, perhaps one can read off a limiting form.

Comment: Specifically, I get $2E_{n+1}=E_{n}\times (1+2p)+E_{n-1}\times(q-p)+1$  Perhaps more usefully written as

Comment: $E_{n+1}=\left(\frac 12+p\right)E_n+\left(\frac 12-p\right)E_{n-1}+1$

Comment: @lulu $+1/2$ on RHS, not $+1$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Absolutely, thank you.  I assume this has a linear solution...the associated homogeneous equation is then easy to solve.

Comment: Indeed, the inhomogeneous equation has the solution $E_n=\frac n{3-2p}$ (unless I botched the arithmetic again), and the homogeneous part has solutions of the form $A+B\left(p-\frac 12\right)^n$ (same caveat), so an exact solution can be written down.  Since $|p-.5|<1$, the $B$ term vanishes for large $n$.

Comment: @lulu, I get $N/(3-2p)$ as well, reasoning as follows. The average string of consecutive T's is $2$, and the average string of consecutive heads is $1/(1-p)$, so if you let $L=2+1/(1-p)=(3-2p)/(1-p)$, then $N$ tosses has (approximately) $k=N/L$ of these averages altogether, so the expected number of heads is approximately $k/(1-p)=N/(3-2p)$.